Power Apps how to change the datasource of a dropdown based on a previous choice
I have an app that updates a sharepoint online list, say "List1".  The form is connected to List1 and inside is a dropdown list that points to another list, List2.  I changed the datasource manually for that list and it all works.  But now I'm combining two different areas and the user picks the area, and I want to change what the second dropdown list is showing.  So if they pick one thing in the LIST1, the second dropdown shows what's in LIST2 but if they pick a different choice, it shows what's in LIST3.  I want to point it to a different list entirely (still on the same sharepoint online site).
For example:  Say I have a dropdown and they can choose CountryA or CountryB.  If they choose CountryA, the next dropdown picks a particular list which has a bunch of cities.  But if they pick CountryB, it changes the list entirely for the next dropdown list, and now has a different list of cities.  I can connect one dropdown to another, but I've never changed datasources based on the results of a previous dropdown.
Is that even possible?

I think it's possible with some workaround and depending on your list. I inserted two dropdowns inside Form,dropdown1 and dropdown2, set dropdown1 item's property ["Vegetables","Flowers"] also inserted gallery (named Gallery3) outside of the form and set it's items property as
If(ddOption.SelectedText.Value="Flowers",
Flowers,
Vegetables)

here Flowers and Vegetables are my sharepoint list, both having colums Name and Color.
Then I set item's property of second dropdown as Gallery3.AllItems and select "Name" field in Value property.
it shows all the names of flowers if flower is selected in dropdown1 and shows names of vegetables if vegetable is selected in dropdown1.

